# which percentiles can be used to better describe the tail distribution

Tags: quantiles, extreme-value, heavy-tailed

I understand that the extreme value distribution is concerned about the density of the tail which describes the losses if I am not wrong.

In such a case which part of the density(expressed as percentiles) of the distribution best characterise the tail distribution.

Comment: Thats of course the percentiles for extreme upper percents, like 99% for example, but really depending on the exact need from the application. What is it you do not understand about these?